# UI Automation: How to find a window

Tags: c++, ui-automation, findwindow

I want to make a program (program 1) that will click a toolbar button on another program (program 2), and for that I want to use UI Automation.

Question:: How do I find the window of another program (program2) with UI Automation? Please show me the function you would use and possibly the header you need for that function to be available.

Comment: How is the other program identified to you? What do you about it that makes it uniquely identifiable? FWIW, you don't use UI Automation to find the initial window handle. Once you have that window handle, that's the route in to UI Automation.

Comment: cool. I already managed to identify the window handle using means not related to UI Automation, but I wanted to see if UI Automation had the means of finding it. Ty for the info

Answer (score 0):

How about [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)? in user32?